# Phone number disappears on Google search results in Firefox 3.6.3

Tags: windows-xp, firefox

I'm running WinXP and Firefox 3.6.3. When I do a search, the Google results page removes all the phone numbers from the results. I can see it in source page view. Is there a conflict say from Skype or soem other add on?

Comment: What happens if you run the search from another IE? In Firefox's safe mode?  in FF with all of your FF extensions disabled?

Comment: An easy way to try with all extensions disabled is to try Firefox(Safemode)

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest the Skype add-on, which I know reformats telephone numbers into links to Skype.  You can try disabling it, from Tools/Add-ons: find Skype in the list, click the Disable button, and restart Firefox.

Comment: Disabling Skype addon did the trick - thanks a bunch!!